# How to allow user to select individual UserControls?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm working on a windows form app containing a TabControl. In one of the TabPages I have a GroupBox that contains a FlowLayoutPanel. I also have a SQL database table containing user notes/comments. Upon form load, I use a SqlDataReader to populate a user control for each note (creation date, note text, username, etc.). The FlowLayoutPanel then gets filled by UserControls. However, I would like for the user to be able to select individual notes/UserControls for editing/deleting. I was initially using a DataGridView instead of UserControls, but notes vary in length and the DataGridView didn't look very organized. My UserControl contains a self-expanding RichTextBox. I thought about adding CheckBoxes next to each UserControl, but I'm not sure how to track which box belongs to which UserControl. Is there a smarter way to accomplish this?

This is a url for a screenshot of the UserControl: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0zUF.jpg
(I don't have enough reputation to post images.)

And here is the code I got from another post on the self-expanding richtextbox:

```vb
Private Sub RichTextBox1_ContentsResized(sender As Object, e As ContentsResizedEventArgs) Handles rtbNote.ContentsResized
    rtbNote.Height = e.NewRectangle.Height + 10
End Sub
```

Comment: Though I'm using vb.net for this project, I included the C# flag because I can understand the language well enough and would be open to suggestions from people more familiar with C#.

Comment: Usually that means your question is too broad as you aren't trying to overcome a specific bug or understand a language feature for example.

Comment: If the checkbox is on/in the UserControl, how can you not know who owns it?  Part of the point of a UC is *encapsulation* include properties in it to expose the info you need (like an identity and `IsChecked` perhaps).